# Swift Runtime exception: unrecognized selector

Tags: swift, macos, unrecognized-selector

In my ViewController class, I have a function:

```
func updateTimes() {
  // (code)
}
```

I create a timer:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

  var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5,
                                   target: self,
                                   selector: 
                                   #selector(ViewController.updateTimes),
                                   userInfo: nil,
                                   repeats: true)
```

The compiler is happy with this.  At runtime, when the timer fires, I get an exception:

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000428b0

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Please show full error message shown in the debug console. And what version of Xcode are you using? Xcode 8 or Xcode 9?

Comment: Where have you initialized the timer? because it works fine if i initiailze it inside viewDidiLoad method. I think timer is getting initialized before the class instance is created thats why getting the error "unrecognized selector "

Comment: Are you sure that the reason of the crash is the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote as a comment on NaGib ToroNgo's answer, he has given us a nice suggestion.

*The selector may not be sent to the instance of `ViewController`.*

I guess the `ViewController` would be taking this form:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimes),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)

    //...(Other property declarations or method definitions)...

    func updateTimes() {
        // (code)
    }
}
```

The variable `timer` is declared as an instance property, and `self` is used in an initial value of `timer`. (In some old versions of Swift, this sort of usage caused error, so I was thinking that this line exists in any of the methods.)

In the current version of Swift (tested with Swift 3.1/Xcode 8.3.3), the code above does not cause error, but `self` is interpreted as a method reference of `self()` method declared in `NSObjectProtocol`. So, `Selector("updateTimes")` is sent to the closure representing the method reference (curried function), not to the instance of the `ViewController`.

The closure does not have a method named `updateTimes`, which caused the exception:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

---

Move the initial value code into some *instance context*, and then `self` represents the instance of the `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer? //<- Keep `timer` as an instance property, but move the initial value code into `viewDidLoad()`.

    //...(Other property declarations or method definitions)...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Do initialize the timer in the instance context.
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5,
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(self.updateTimes),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
        //...
    }

    //In Swift 3, `@objc` is not needed, just for a preparation for Swift 4
    @objc func updateTimes() {
        // (code)
    }
}
```

I believe this does not cause `unrecognized selector` exception.

Comment: Thank, you, that fixed the exception!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided seems perfect. I think the problem is, somehow your view controller is getting released or having dangling pointer.

Comment: `Timer` calls its target action always as an instance method. (`#selector(ViewController.updateTimes)` is exactly the same thing as `#selector(self.updateTimes)`.) The target is `self`, not its class.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have mistaken one thing.

Comment: The target is `self` and in some context it represents a class object (metaclass). So, your suggestion would work. (But not because the selector is written as `#selector(ViewController.updateTimes)`, but because `self` in that context represents a class object.)

Comment: @OOPer i have changed my answer please check now.

Comment: Watching. Your explanation in your old answer contained a little fault, but you suggested us a very nice thing. Thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer. You were very near to the right place.

Comment: Sorry, again. With a little more exploration, I found that `self` in that context represents the `self` method itself (as a curried function). But still the fact that your intuition lead me to the right place does not change. Thanks again and sorry for some mistakes in my old comments made you confused.

Answer (score 0):

Its time to say good bye to selectors!!! use the below code

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        // check self for nil before using
    }
```